# Python 3.7: Utility of Dataclasses and SimpleNameSpace

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

Python 3.7 provides new `dataclasses` which have predefined special functions.

From an overview point, `dataclasses` and `SimpleNamespace` both provide nice data encapsulating facility.

```
@dataclass
class MyData:
    name:str
    age: int

data_1 = MyData(name = 'JohnDoe' , age = 23)

data_2 = SimpleNamespace(name = 'JohnDoe' , age = 23)
```

A lot of times I use `SimpleNamespace` just to wrap data and move it around.

I even subclass it to add special functions:

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

class NewSimpleNameSpace(SimpleNamespace):
    def __hash__(self):
        return some_hashing_func(self.__dict__)
```

For my question:

1. How does someone choose between `SimpleNamespace` and `dataclasses`?
2. Why were they necessary, when the same effect can be achieved with extending the `SimpleNamespace`?
3. What all other use cases `dataclasses` cater to?

Comment: SimpleNamespace only adds the attributes and a `__repr__`. dataclass adds much more, e.g. `__eq__`, `__hash__`, ..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is that this is all covered by [PEP 557](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/).  Taking your questions slightly out of order...

#### Why?

1. To leverage PEP 526 to provide a simple way to define such classes.
2. To support static type checkers.

#### How to pick when to use them?

The PEP is quite clear that they are not a replacement and expect the other solutions to have their own place.

Like any other design decision, you'll therefore need to decide exactly what features you care about.  If that includes the following, you definitely don't want dataclasses.

> Where is it not appropriate to use Data Classes?
>
> API compatibility with tuples or dicts is required.
>      Type validation beyond that provided by PEPs 484 and 526 is required, or value validation or conversion is required.

That said, the same is true for SimpleNameSpace, so what else can we look at to decide?  Let's take a closer look at the extra features provided by dataclasses...

The existing definition of SimpleNameSpace is as follows:

> A simple object subclass that provides attribute access to its namespace, as well as a meaningful repr.

The python docs then go on to say that it provides a simple `__init__`, `__repr__` and `__eq__` implementation.  Comparing this to PEP 557, dataclasses also give you options for:

- ordering - comparing the class as if it were a tuple of its fields, in order.
- immutability - where assigning to fields will generate an exception
- control of the hashing - though this isn't recommended.

Clearly, then, you should use dataclasses if you care about ordering or immutability (or need the niche hashing control).

#### Other use cases?

None that I can see, though you could argue that the initial "why?" covers other use cases.

Comment: I would point out that it also depends on how structured your data is. If there is a clear type/object model, dataclasses are more explicit as to what should be in the object. Also, class features like `__slots__` makes more sense with dataclasses than SimpleNamespace

Comment: @EdwardMinnix Can you write that as an answer? It is a usecase worth discussing.

Answer (score 16):

Dataclasses is much more like `namedtuple` and the popular [attrs](http://www.attrs.org) package than `SimpleNamespace` (which isn't even mentioned in [the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/)). They serve two different intended purposes.

**Dataclasses**

- Structured
- Typed (by default, but optional)
- Writes most of the boilerplate for basic dunder methods (`__init__`, `__hash__`, `__eq__`, and many more)
- Provide easy mechanism for default values for attributes
- Can easily add `__slots__` and methods

**SimpleNamespace**

- "Grab bag" data structure
- Used where you need more than a dictionary but less than a class
- Not intended to be use things like `__slots__`

From the `SimpleNamespace` documentation:

> SimpleNamespace may be useful as a replacement for `class NS: pass`. However, for a structured record type use `namedtuple()` instead.

Since `@dataclass` is supposed to replace a lot of the use cases of `namedtuple`, named records/structs should be done with `@dataclass`, not `SimpleNamespace`.

You may also want to look at [this PyCon talk by Raymond Hettinger](https://pyvideo.org/pycon-us-2018/dataclasses-the-code-generator-to-end-all-code-generators.html), where he goes into the backstory of `@dataclass` and it's use.