# How do I create an object that has no class in Python?

Tags: python

I am using the `object` **function** (**`object()`**) to *make an object **without a class*** in **Python** but it does not have any attributes or arguments, so I am trying to customise it by *creating a variable* like `thing = object()` and then using `setattr(thing, 'name', 'Marco')` ***but*** it won't let me because it throws an error saying:

```
>>> thing = object()
>>> setattr(thing, 'name', 'nothing')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'name'
```

How do I get past this?
I don't get why it does this when `object` can't have attributes but the object function can (`object()`) and then it throws `AttributeError` when I try to set an attribute for the object that is assigned to the variable when the whole point of using `setattr()` is to set attributes lol

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't set attributes on instance of "object" class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529002/cant-set-attributes-on-instance-of-object-class)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907937/adding-attributes-to-python-objects

Comment: Every Python object has a class. What problem are you trying to solve by creating an object without a class?

Comment: Why don't you create a class with the attributes you require?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be clear, `object()` has a class (the class is `object`); it's impossible to have an instance without a class in Python.

That said, plain `object` doesn't have storage for arbitrary attributes. If you want a minimalist object that lets you make arbitrary attributes, use `types.SimpleNamespace`, e.g.:

```
import types  # At top of file

thing = types.SimpleNamespace()
setattr(thing, 'name', 'nothing')
```

Of course, `setattr` isn't necessary here since you're using known attribute names. Just use normal attribute assignment instead:

```
thing.name = 'nothing'
```

If you're really using dynamic attribute names via `setattr`, you're probably better off skipping attributes entirely, and just using a `dict` with `dict` lookup syntax:

```
thing = {}
thing['name'] = 'nothing'
```

Comment: I'd never heard of `SimpleNamespace` before today, neat! What are the differences between a `SimpleNamespace` and a `dataclass`? Seems like they do roughly the same thing. EDIT: never mind, I found this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51082418/python-3-7-utility-of-dataclasses-and-simplenamespace

Comment: @ShadowRanger Your "solution" literally involves using classes

Comment: @MarcoEl-Korashy: Because it's literally impossible to avoid using classes. *Everything* in Python is an object, and all objects are instances of a class. The answer does explain that difficulty, and it does offer solutions that uses a minimalist built-in class to avoid defining new user-defined classes (which I suspect was the OP's goal).